# C# How to start from line 0 in richtextbox with loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Okay my question is probably very simple for some of you but I can not figure it out. So let's say I have

```
String.Split( );
```

I add it to array, then if I want to print the content of the array I use

```
foreach (string s in splitarray)
{
  Richtextbox1.Text = Richtextbox1.Text + s;
}
```

This way I keep the oldcontent and I print the new one ontop. But my problem is that it starts from Line[1] because as it appears the textbox already had an empty line inserted.

Comment: How are you splitting the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string s in splitarray)
{
  if(Richtextbox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)//Checking for first Array Item
  {
   Richtextbox1.Text =  s;
  }
  else
  {
   Richtextbox1.Text = Richtextbox1.Text + s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will be having `space in first element of splitarray`. You can skip the element at zero index if it is empty string to avoid the first empty line in Richtextbox1.

```
foreach (int i = 0; i < splitarray.Length; i++)
{
  if(i == 0 && splitarray[i].Trim() != String.Empty)
     Richtextbox1.Text = Richtextbox1.Text + s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 for(int i = 0; i < splitarray.Length; i++)
{
Richtextbox1.Text = Richtextbox1.Text + splitarray[i];
}
```

Comment: Apart from not concatenating the values, this will do nothing to solve the "problem".

Comment: @Oded He wants to print the values of array and it will do that

Comment: In every iteration, the value in `Richtextbox1.Text` will be overwritten. That is not what the OP is asking.